# How to add support of scala syntax highlighting in VIM?

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting, scala

How to configure VIM to be able to highlight scala language (`.scala` files extension)?

Current VIM configuration (.vimrc file): 

`:syntax on`

Answer (score 4):

1. Download the `scala.vim` file from here http://github.com/vim-scripts/scala.vim to e.g. `~/.vim/syntax` directory.
2. Edit your `~/.vimrc` file and add the following:

   ```
   au BufRead,BufNewFile *.scala set filetype=scala
   au! Syntax scala source ~/.vim/syntax/scala.vim
   ```

---

source: [Scala syntax highlighting in VIM](https://cloudfysh.wordpress.com/2010/11/02/scala-syntax-highlighting-in-vim/)